# Как заменить данный код кнопки на надпись (ссылку)?

Tags: html

```
<div>
<input type="button" onclick="$('#two').jGrowl('Сообщение в левом нижнем углу экрана');" value="Bottom Left"/>
</div>
<div id="two" class="jGrowl bottom-left"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Хм. Надо переписать вместо элемента `<input>` элемент `<a>`. Если нужно по нажатию кнопки отправлять форму, добавить обработчик `document.someform.submit()` на клик.

```
<a href="..." onclick="...">Bottom Left</a>
```